# Pixel Art: Can't create "hero walking" animation

Tags: animation, pixel-art, image-sprite

I'm creating a game and animating my hero image using sprite sheets, but I can't seem to manage creating the walk cycle animation - the output is a weird animation that looks like the hero is just shaking its legs.

Note that the "hero's legs" are made up of 3 pixels each, that are upscaled twice.

**[Here is the sprite sheet:][3]**

[image: spritesheet]

the first 6 frames make the walking animation.

Comment: Have you been playing fez by any chance? ;) ...ahh your have, just read you post haha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case the character's legs are just vertical triangles, I can imagine the walk only by "scissors" movement, i.e. horizontal shift of lower vertices one to another.

Your picture is  very blurred, it is difficult to realise what is happening there.

Probably, it is worths to create more complicated character.

[image] - if you open this image in gif-editor, you can see isolated pictures creating the walk.

And...you can find thousands of tutorials via Google inserting "walking cycle" and "walking animation pictures".

Comment: You can click in the "Here is the sprite sheet:" title in my question to access the full-res version of the sprite (and open it in a image editor if you think that it's difficult to see the image in a white background). Anyway, thanks for your answer.